# Find a maximizing solution to an ODE which depends on a paramater function

Tags: differential-equations, calculus-of-variations, classical-mechanics

*(For the physical meaning of this problem see https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/122818/how-should-i-throttle-my-rocket-to-reach-highest-altitude).*

Given $g \in (0,\infty), k \in C^1( [0, \infty)), f \in L^1([0, \infty))$ non negative and such that $\int_0^{\infty}f \leq c < 1$, consider the Cauchy problem
$$\begin{cases}
x_f''(t)= \dfrac{f(t) - x_f'(t)^2k(x_f(t))}{1-\int_0^{\infty} f} -g,\\
x_f'(0) = 0,\\
x_f(0) = 0.
\end{cases}
$$

Find an $f$ such that for any other $\tilde f$ (which satisfy the properties above) it holds
$$ \sup_{[0,\infty)} x_{\tilde f} \leq \sup_{[0,\infty)} x_f. $$
(You may also want to consider the weak formulation with distributional derivatives).

---

Are there some analytic solutions to this problem for easy forms of $k$? (e.g. $k$ constant, linear, etc.)

What can we say about the regularity of solutions in the weak problem?

Can we derive from the form of $k$ some properties of the solution?

Comment: The formulation is meaningless as is: throttle once and fly to the infinite height because $x''=-K(x')^2$ gives $x'\approx 1/t$, so the integral diverges (the drag alone cannot stop the flight). It would be smart to take the gravity into account, after which the setup becomes meaningful. Ever heard of Bellman equations?

Comment: @fedja Of course, thank you, added the $g$

Answer (score 1):

I doubt you'll be satisfied with this answer. Suppose that $k(x_f) = \kappa \in (0,\infty)$ is constant (if $\kappa = 0$ everything is straight forward). Fix $C < 1$ and choose $0 < \epsilon << 1$. Set $$a = \frac{\epsilon + (1-C)g}{C}$$ and define $$f = C a \chi_{[0,\frac{1}{a}]}$$ where $\chi$ is the characteristic function of the interval $[0,\frac{1}{a}]$. Notice that $\int_0^\infty f = C$. Plugging this function into the above and considering it only over the interval $[0,\frac{1}{a}]$ we have that $$(1-C)y_f' + \kappa y_f^2 = f(t) - (1-C)g = \epsilon$$ where $y_f = x_f'$. Now, thinking about this a lot I found that $y_f = A \tanh(B t)$ is a solution to this equation with $A = \sqrt{\frac{\epsilon}{\kappa}}$ and $B = \frac{\kappa A}{1 - C}$. Thus, $x_f = \int_0^t y_f$. Note that $x_f$ satisfies all the initial conditions you've requested. Remember, this is what the solution looks like only on the interval $[0,\frac{1}{a}]$.

OK, now let's get into $x_f$ a bit more. One can show that $$ x_f(\frac{1}{a}) = \frac{A}{B} \log[\cosh(\frac{B}{a})] > \frac{1 - C}{\kappa} \log[\frac{e^{B/a}}{2}] = \sqrt{\frac{\epsilon}{\kappa}} \frac{C}{\epsilon + (1-C)g}$$ Sooo, we can take $C$ as close to 1 as we want to and $\epsilon$ really small to show that $\forall M>0$ we can find $f$ so that $$\sup_{t\in[0,\infty)} x_f > M$$

Maybe in your problem you don't want to assume that the mass of the rocket can be arbitrarily small? This would rule out the above construction.

Comment: If I understand correctly, your answer says: as the ratio (dry mass):(fuel mass) goes to $0$ the "rocket" will be able to reach any altitude. This is a nice insight but is not what the question was really about

Comment: @Brainstorming All I'm showing is that if this ratio does go to zero, then no such $f$ exists that you are asking for.

Comment: Oh right thank you, I actually forgot to ask that $$\int_0^{\infty} f \leq C < 1.$$ I corrected the statement